# Copy last row to another spreadsheet upon form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with an Add-on that takes data from a form and runs on form submission. I also have another Add-on that pushes the data from this spreadsheet to another spreadsheet - let's call it spreadheet2 here. In spreadsheet2 I have my own script with a function copyLastRow() that copies the last row from this spreadsheet to another spreadsheet - let's call it spreadsheet3. My script is supposed to append a new row from spreadsheet2 to spreadsheet3. It runs OK when I run it manually, but it is not running via the project trigger - which I installed for Script editor's Resources - I tried both on Edit and on Change triggers, but they are simply not firing up when data is pushed from spreadsheet2. The script is working when I actually edit spreadsheet2. However, this is not good for what I need - I really need the script to work without manual intervention. Can you, please, help?

```
function copyLastRow() {  
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 53).getValues();
target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
```

EDIT: I updated the code - I realized I left the previous version of code here.

Comment: What is your specific problem? What have you tried already, to resolve it?

Comment: My script works, but I just want to make sure it will run every time a form is submitted even if two or more users submit a form at the same time. Just checking if I should add some more code to the script.

Comment: @Mogsdad  I edited my post above to make it clearer - well, i hope I made it clearer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the trigger function in spreadsheet2? Is it the `copyLastRow()` function you've shown, or do you have something else call this one? What is the purpose of the `sheet` parameter, and why do you over-write it with a var of the same name?

Comment: @Mogsdad I am afraid that I am not an experienced coder - far from it. The only trigger or triggers I tried are those that I installed from the Resources of the Script editor as follows: copyToSheet From Spreadsheet on Change on Edit). Is overwriting it with a var of the same name a mistake?

Comment: @Mogsdad I edited the code above - I realized I had an earlier version there. Sorry about that. i very much hope you'll be able to help.

Comment: @Mogsdad I added a comment below your answer. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Mogsdad thank you so much for your most helpful and clear answers. I apologize for asking yet another question: if the sheet that accepts responses from a form contains an additional column with data, is it possible to copy that along with event.values?

Comment: @mogsdad I had to ask another question below your answer - very sorry about that.

Comment: @mogsdad I've just asked another question on eventvalues and offset. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to worry about whether this function will be effective when multiple users are submitting forms... it won't be. But it's easily improved.

What's the problem? When `copyLastRow()` runs, it assumes that the last row of the source spreadsheet contains the response that also triggered the function. However, before it gets around to reading that row, another user might submit a form. (Eventually, the function will be triggered by that submission as well, and could process the same row a second time.)

The simplest improvement in this situation is to take advantage of the event object that is provided to the trigger function as a parameter. See [Google Sheet Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) for some background details.

The newly submitted responses are in `event.values`, which is an array - exactly what is needed for `.appendRow()`. Here's how we can update your `copyLastRow` function:

```
function copyLastRow(event) {  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  target.appendRow(event.values);
}
```

Now it doesn't matter how many users submit forms - each will be handled uniquely by this function.

Comment: if you can bear with me: how do I define e.values in my code? I assume I should set up variables for each column as follows: var Timestamp = e.values[0] and so on. I assume I keep the lastrow var in my code. I tried to run the code both manually and with the installable trigger on form submission, bt I get an error saying "ReferenceError: "e" is not defined." Very sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: I had a typo... most examples show `e`, I intended to use `event` for clarity, but missed one edit. Fixed now. Sorry about that - just change `e` to `event`.

Comment: I am very embarrassed to ask, but would it be possible for you to show he updated code in full? I looked at the documentation and various examples, but I am just not getting it right as I get error messages. I'll keep trying, but I very much hope, you'll get back to me.

Comment: Sorry. Mogsdad, I've just managed to get this code running. I was testing this code manually and it didn't work. I didn't realize that it can run only on installable triggers. I am so excited by this. I'll do a few more tests and come back to you.

Comment: This is so good, but the only problem is that the Response sheet has an additional column which runs on CopyDown formula and this column data also needs to be copied to the target. Would that be possible at all? Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, another thing: in the target sheet I also need to have another column that is based on data validation (yes, No). This would be filled in manually after the last rows are copied. Would the code still work with this column?

Comment: The event object includes the range that has been updated, so use that with `offset` to grab the additional cell(s) - again, independent of other form submissions.

Comment: I am very glad to hear from you, but if you can bear with mt, I really don't know how I can use offset in your code. Very sorry to have to ask again.

Comment: @Mica - better you should put that into a new question, with the relevant details.