# Event values and offset in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I had fantastic help from @Mogsdad on another issue here:

[Copy last row to another spreadsheet upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358310/google-spreadsheet-copy-last-row-to-another-spreadsheet/26451570)

```
function copyLastRow(event) {  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  target.appendRow(event.values);
}
```

This script works extremely well - it copies the last added row from the original source with form responses to another spreadsheet. It copies all the values from the form, but on the original spreadsheet with responses I have an additional column which is not part of the submission form. I need to copy data from this column as well.
I had a reply from Mogsdad which says that the event object includes the range that has been updated, so I should use that with offset to grab the additional cell(s).
I searched everywhere for any examples with eventvalues and offset, but failed to find anything. I would very much appreciate any help with this as I don't have much experience. Thanks.

Comment: @mogsdad I just replied below.

Comment: @mogsdad  and serge insas I replied below your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Event object includes a `range` property that tells us where the latest form response has been placed in the sheet. All methods for [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) can be applied to this range. For example, `.getWidth()` will return the range width, giving us a starting point for expanding the range to copy.

Since we want to get the cells from the response plus one (or more) additional columns from the sheet, we can use the [`offset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29) method to expand the original range. (Note that `offset()` is a range method - it does not apply to the `event.values` array.)

```
function copyLastRow(event) {  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sourceWidth = event.range.getWidth() + additionalColumns; // define a value here
  // Grab all the cells in this response, plus additionalColumns
  var sourceRange = event.range.offset(0,0,1,sourceWidth);
  target.appendRow(sourceRange.getValues()[0]);
}
```

Note that because we use the information from the event object, this function remains tolerant to multiple form submissions.

Comment: that's great - many thanks. Before I try this script, can I ask this: I have only one additional column after the columns that are input from the form. Let's say there are 7 columns and the additional column is number 8. How would I define this in your script? Sorry for asking, I just want to make sure I don't make a mistake as all this is new to me.

Comment: The answer is in Mogsdad's code:  additionalColumn has to be defined, in your example make it =1.

Comment: Yes, I did run the code before I asked the question and ran it again after Serge insas comment, but I get this error: Range.offset([0, 0, 1, 8]) [0 seconds]
Execution failed: Cannot find method appendRow((class)). (line 7, file "Code") [0.135 seconds total runtime]

Comment: I changed the last two lines of the code to: var sourceRange = event.range.offset(0,0,1,sourceWidth).getValues();
  target.appendRow(sourceRange[0]); and it ran fine. Would that be correct?

Comment: The only problem is that the additional column copies the formula down in the original spreadsheet and so the next two submissions I did came over without the last column filled because the column was not filled yet. So there is a time lag. Can something be done about it or is it impossible?

Comment: I added Utilities.sleep(1500) before the execution of the code and submitted the form two times in quick succession. Everything copied over including the last column. The question is whether this will be reliable for every submission? Sorry for adding so many comments - I very much appreciate any help, indeed.

Comment: That would work, but I recommend you be very careful about naming your objects to avoid confusion. When you append `getValues()` to `sourceRange`, the result is no longer a Range, so the name is misleading. Check the updated code; I'd forgotten a pair of brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am still struggling with offset - this is fine if I have a form with one page, but I ran the code on a form which is divided into two pages. If a user clicks No to further questions, then the form is submitted. If the user clicks Yes, it gets him to the next page to answer more questions and then he/she can submit the form. So I have 53 columns altogether, column number 53 is the additional column. Whatever I put as a value for the additional column it doesn't work. It works on the shorter form with 8 columns - but I am still not sure how to define the value.

Comment: In the industry, we call this "requirement creep" - new or previously un-expressed requirements that invalidate previous assumptions. Often they ultimately lead to unclear and unmaintainable code. (While in the StackOverflow world, it merits a separate question.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know. I'll make sure it won't happen again. Your code runs perfectly on both short and longer forms, provided all the columns are filled in. I wasn't aware of the problem that would arise with a two-page form if the second page is not filled in. I'll create a new question. Very sorry about that.